# Or и конструкция If,elif,else

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксис

Есть простенький бот в ВК:

```
import random

import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType



def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.randint(0, 2048)})


# API-ключ созданный ранее
token = "9t0ken321ne56pokazy ;)"

# Авторизуемся как сообщество
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

# Работа с сообщениями
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)


print("Бот запущен")
# Основной цикл
for event in longpoll.listen():

    # Если пришло новое сообщение
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        # Если оно имеет метку для меня( то есть бота)
        if event.to_me:

            # Сообщение от пользователя
            request = event.text

            # Каменная логика ответа
            write_msg(event.user_id, request)
            if request == "привет" :
                write_msg(event.user_id, "Хай")
            elif request == "Помощь":
                write_msg(event.user_id, 'Напиши ему "привет" или "пока".Он ещё молод и глуп,и способен только на это')
            elif request == "пока" :
                write_msg(event.user_id, "Пока((")
            else:
                write_msg(event.user_id, 'write_msg(event.user_id, request)')
```

когда пытаюсь куда-либо ввести or к примеру:

```
elif request == "Помощь" or "help":
                    write_msg(event.user_id, 'Напиши ему "привет" или "пока".Он ещё молод и глуп,и способен только на это')
```

Бот на каждое сообщение отвечает этим сообщением.
С чем это может быть связано?

(Можно конечно elif отдельно написать ещё раз, но хочется разобраться из-за чего так происходит)

Comment: `elif request in ("Помощь", "help"):`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что после `or` надо прописывать условие полностью, то есть `elif request == "Помощь" or request == "help":`. Отвечает на все сообщения подобным образом он потому, что любая непустая строка отдаёт `True`, и условие выполняется:

```
In[1]: if "help":
           print("True")
Out[1]: True
```

Comment: отнюдь не любая - `''` выдаст `False`, просто люди, составляющие такие условия далеко не знакомы с алгеброй высказываний..

Comment: @finally только хотел это написать. Только любая непустая строка вернет `True`